# Is it possible to give backgroud color in jqgrid setGroupHeaders or Vertical lines to segregate it from column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is my setGroupHeaders Code. Is it possible to give background color to these column.

```js
jQuery("#plist").jqGrid('setGroupHeaders', {
  useColSpanStyle: false,
  groupHeaders: [{
    startColumnName: 'A',
    numberOfColumns: 1,
    titleText: ''
  }, {
    startColumnName: 'B',
    numberOfColumns: 3,
    titleText: 'My First header'
  }, {
    startColumnName: 'E',
    numberOfColumns: 2,
    titleText: 'second Header'
  }]
});
```

Comment: Could you describe more detailed what you need to implement? Where you want to add a vertical line? You can include a picture, which explain your requirements. Additionally it's important to write which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7).

Comment: I am using the 4.4.3 version of the jqgrid. My requirement is i want to change background colour of setgroupheader, in above example the second column where title is 'My First Header' should be different colour that other, and all three ColSpan column should show only that color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I want to remind, that jqGrid 4.4.3 is almost 5 years old, which is very old for web development. Is it wirklich required to use the retro version? I'd recommend you to upgrade to the latest version (4.15.1) of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).

I'm not sure that I correctly understand where you want to change the background color. I suppose that you need to use something like the following CSS rule:

```css
.jqg-second-row-header > th.ui-th-column-header {
    background-color: orange; /* change background color */
    background-image: none;   /* remove default background-image */
    color: blue;   /* change the color of the text to correspond background color */
    height: 1.7em; /* increase the height of the header line */
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/eba8z5jm/

If you would need to set different background colors on different column headers, then you can modify the above CSS rule to for example

```css
.jqg-second-row-header > th.ui-th-column-header:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: orange; /* change background color */
    background-image: none;   /* remove default background-image */
    color: blue;   /* change the color of the text to correspond background color */
    height: 1.7em; /* increase the height of the header line */
}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/eba8z5jm/3/

Comment: This is the exactly what i was looking for. Thank you for your help @Oleg. Thank you very much.